# How to reverse a sentence in C and display it uppercased?

Tags: c, reverse, uppercase

I have a program that works but not the way I wanted, I want to write sentences back to front and in uppercase, but now I am reading the first word from the sentence and the answer is 1 word in uppercase and the next is the same word only in lower case.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char* reverse(char* str);

int main(void) {
    char word[200];

    printf("enter a sentence: ");
    scanf("%s", word);
    
    printf(" %s\n", reverse(word));

    return 0;
}

char* reverse(char *str) {
    size_t i = strlen(str);
    char* reversed = malloc(sizeof *reversed * (i + 1));

    if (reversed) {
        size_t j = 0;
        while (i > 0) {
          i--;
          reversed[j] = str[i]; 
          j++;
        }
        reversed[j] = '\0';
    }

    int t = 0;
    char ch;

    while (str[t]) {
        ch = reversed[t];
        putchar(toupper(ch));
        t++;
    }

    return reversed;
}
```

here is what i get

```
enter a sentence: hello world
OLLEH olleh
```

I need the program to read the sentence and display it backwards and in uppercase.

Comment: Did you reasd the spec for `"%s"` in the scanf doc? Especially what it does when it encounters a white space? It explains why your code never sees "world".

Comment: what should i use instead "%s"?

Comment: If you want to read a line instead of a single white-space-separated word, then use a different function. E.g. `fgets()`. Not `gets()`! Then you can check your code for the separate mistake to print the single word twice. By the way, because I was wondering, if you name the receiving buffer `word`, it seems that you already forshadowed that it only would contain a single word.... Were you consciously aware?

Comment: Tip: Stop using `scanf`. Get used to writing your own simple parsers using a loop and a `switch`. `scanf` can do a very small number of things fairly well, but it's otherwise extremely limiting.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

As other users already suggested to you, don't use `scanf`, instead use `fgets`. This is because `scanf` reads only the first word of the sentence (up to the first space). To read the entire sentence (including spaces) use `fgets`

Here's a fix to your code:

```
int main(void) {
  char word[200];
  printf("enter a sentence: ");
  fgets(word, sizeof word, stdin);
  printf("%s\n", reverse(word));
  return 0;
}

char* reverse(char *str) {
  size_t i = strlen(str);
  char* reversed = malloc(sizeof *reversed * (i + 1));
  
  if (reversed) {
    size_t j = 0;
    while (i > 0) {
      i--;
      reversed[j] = toupper(str[i]);
      j++;
    }
    reversed[j] = '\0';
  }
  return reversed;
}
```

I've added a call to `toupper()` before storing in the `reversed` string.
I've removed also the second loop that prints the reversed string in uppercase because that's not needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The format string `%s` allows to read characters until a white space character is encountered.

If you want to read a sentence consisting from several words then instead of this call of `scanf`

```
scanf("%s", word);
```

you should write

```
scanf("%199[^\n]", word);
```

Your function reverse is declared like

```
char* reverse(char* str);
```

That is its parameter does not have qualifier `const`. It means that the passed string should be reversed in place within the function. Otherwise if the function creates a new string then it should be declared with the qualifier `const` like

```
char* reverse(const char* str);
```

This while loop

```
while (str[t]) {
    ch = reversed[t];
    putchar(toupper(ch));
    t++;
}
```

does not convert characters of the result string to uppercase. It just outputs characters in upper case while you need to convert to upper case characters of the result string.

Using your approach to the function definition it can be written the following way

```
char * reverse( const char *str ) 
{
    size_t n = strlen( str );
    char *reversed = malloc( n + 1 );

    if ( reversed ) 
    {
        reversed[n] = '\0';
        
        while ( n-- )
        {
            reversed[n] = toupper( ( unsigned char )*str++ ); 
        }
    }

    return reversed;
}
```

And in main you should write

```
char word[200];

printf("enter a sentence: ");
scanf( "%199[^\n]", word );

char *reversed = reverse( word ); 

if ( reversed ) puts( reversed );

free( reversed );
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *reverse( const char *str )
{
    size_t n = strlen( str );
    char *reversed = malloc( n + 1 );

    if (reversed)
    {
        reversed[n] = '\0';

        while (n--)
        {
            reversed[n] = toupper( ( unsigned char )*str++ );
        }
    }

    return reversed;
}

int main( void )
{
    char word[] = "hello world";

    char *reversed = reverse( word );

    if (reversed) puts( reversed );

    free( reversed );
}
```

The program output is

```
DLROW OLLEH
```

Also as the function does not change the passed string but makes a reversed copy of it then it would be better to name the function as for example `reverse_copy_toupper`.